# Consider structural breaks in VECM

Tags: r, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, structural-change

I am implementing a VECM, which should also take two structural breaks into account. I am using the function `ca.jo` from the "vars" package in R and include the dummy variables, according to Joyeux (2007) in the `dumvar` argument of the function.
I estimate a system of three endogenous variables and five lags. If I follow Joyeux (2007: p. 8-10), my matrix of all dummy variables should include the following variables and lagged variables.

$D_{1,t}$: Intervention Dummy for the first break, which is 1 after the first break until the second and 0 otherwise

$D_{2,t}$: Intervention Dummy for the second break, which is 1 after the second break

$I_{1,t}$: Indicator Dummy for the first break, which is 1 on the observation after the first break and 0 otherwise.

$I_{2,t}$: Indicator Dummy for the second break, which is 1 on the observation after the second break and 0 otherwise.

Additionally I include the trend times the $D_{j,t}$ dummies and lag the four dummy variables with five lags. This leads to issues, that matrices can't be inverted in the `ca.jo` function, so there must be something wrong. So I somehow cause problems, with all these dummies and lagged dummy variables, and I am not sure, what I am missing here.

**References**

- Joyeux, R. (2007). How to deal with structural breaks in practical cointegration analysis? In B. B. Rao (ed.), Cointegration for the Applied Economist, Second Edition, Palgrave Macmillan, New York, 195-221.

Comment: Did you manually check whether there is no perfect multicollinearity between your variables? You can do that by regressing one on all the others and seeing whether you get a perfect fit. Also, what exactly is the error message of the `ca.jo` function? Also, could you give a full reference to Joyeux (2007)?

Comment: No, I didn't check it manually. The error I am getting is  
`ca.jo(dt.myVariables[, c(myvars), with = FALSE], type = "trace", spec="longrun", ecdet = "none", season = NULL, dumvar = cbind(dt.myVariables[,myexogenvar, with = FALSE], dummat), K = 5)
Error in solve.default(M11) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.72076e-25`  
The full citation is Joyeux, R. (2007). How to deal with structural breaks in practical cointegration analysis? In B. B. Rao (ed.), Cointegration for the Applied Economist, Second Edition, Palgrave Macmillan, New York, 195-221.

Comment: I created a gist file, to give a better idea, how the dummy matrix dummat looks like.
[gist on github](https://gist.github.com/hannes101/57d88a126a479eae2029)

Comment: I noted above that it is easy to check it manually. Using your variable names, check whether the dummy matrix does not suffer from perfect multicollinearity: `lm(dummat[,1]~dummat[,-1])`. Also, `cbind` the dummy matrix with all the other variables (and their lags) in the model and do the same (because the multicollinearity may be not within `dummat` but within all the regressors).

Comment: I was just doing this and noted, that the lagged values of $I_{j,t}$ are all removed due to singularities. When reading it again it seems that in the multivariate case I don't need these lagged values, when leaving them out only $I_{2,t}$ is removed. I will further  investigate, what is actually necessary in my case.

Comment: I haven't looked at the article nor do I use R but the dummies which are restricted to the cointegration space and the one's which are included in the equations for differences should not be the same. Dummy variables in a cointegrated VAR model vs. a multivariate linear regression model are not the same. For example a "mean-shift" dummy in first differences, (.....,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,....) accumulates to a trend in the level variables, (....,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,....).

Comment: See The Cointegrated VAR Model Methodology and Applications (https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-cointegrated-var-model-9780199285679?cc=dk&lang=en&) chapter 6 (section 6.5) for a discussion on how dummy variables in first differences accumulate when included in the levels (think of a constant which accumulates to a trend under a unit root. The dummies accumulate in a similar fashion). I am guessing that could be one of your problems.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is taken care of, when using the definitions of the dummy variables in the Joyeux (2007) chapter. Although the difference might be in the modelling of the VECM between the article and the ca.jo() function. So that's probably also where my issues might come from.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't solve it completely, but what I did so far, was to add several options to the ca.jo() function to incorporate additional cases directly. I also think, that one needs to incorporate only the k-th lag of the $D_{j,t}$ dummy and k-1 lags for the $I_{j,t}$ dummy.
You can take a look at the current state at my github repo.
https://github.com/hannes101/CointegrationAnalysis
Also posted it to the r-sig-finance mailing list 
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2015q4/013594.html